# I can su root, but can not log in as root?

Tags: permissions, ssh, sudo, root

Usually, it is the other way around...so this might be the first from what I researched.

lets say i log on to my server venus as willc86. When I su root, it lets me in.
however, lets say I ssh venus -l root, it wont let me. access denied. if I ssh venus -l willc86
it works, but I have to su root in order to switch

is this a ssh problem?

Comment: Most likely ssh in as root is disabled. Take a look at /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: see also http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/SSH_security

Answer (score 0):

As bodhi.zazen mentions, root log in from ssh might be disabled.

Honestly, this is not a bad thing. You might want to consider getting used to having to "su -" to root if you have to (or sudo -i if you use it).

Try the following to check,

```
grep PermitRootLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

If you see the following come by, root login is disabled.

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

Or if the output is the following, root login cannot be done with passwords:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

To change this setting, use your favorite text editor (vi/nano) and change no to "yes"

Again, consider getting used to working with "su -/sudo" when needed before changing this.

EDIT/Sidenote:
Also, this will only work if you actually set a password for the root user.

Comment: thanks people! ill check it out. reason i ask is because i am using clonezilla and using root to access

Comment: `PermitRootLogin without-password` will NOT ALLOW password aughtntication, so setting a root password is irrlevant with that option. `without-password` will allow login with keys or other methods such as Kerbos.

Comment: also, if you look at the ssh logs, ssh in root us a very very common crack for script kiddies, so I would not suggest you allow login as root with a password. Use a key ;)